# I can't write text to NSTextField Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I've spent much time finding an answer but I don't understand how right it googling.

I just need to create a simple text field. I've done it but I can't write some text.
After build and run I tried to write but the text was written in x-code window.
What's wrong?

I guess it's related to focus NSWindow or NSApplication.

It's very strange because I can call the context menu and I see cut/copy/paste functions. I even can use those but I can write text by the keyboard.

All code already in *main.m*

```objectivec
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Window : NSWindow {
    NSTextField* textBox1;
    NSTextField* textBox2;
}
- (instancetype)init;
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Window : NSWindow
- (instancetype)init {
    NSTextField* textBox1 = [[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 270, 100, 20)] autorelease];
    [textBox1 setStringValue:@"textBox1"];
  
    NSTextField* textBox2 = [[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 230, 100, 20)] autorelease];
    [textBox2 setStringValue:@"textBox2"];
    
    [super initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 300, 300)
                     styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable | NSWindowStyleMaskUnifiedTitleAndToolbar
                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                         defer:NO];
    [self setTitle:@"TextBox Example"];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:textBox1];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:textBox2];
    [self makeFirstResponder:textBox2];
    [self setIsVisible:YES];
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender {
    [NSApp terminate:sender];
    return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    [[[Window alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [application activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    
    [NSApp run];
}
```

[image: NSTextField]

Comment: Under what class are you writing code?  Well, do it through a view controller.

Comment: You cannot do init method like this. need to call designated initializer [super init]. For NSWindow it is - (instancetype)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)style backing:(NSBackingStoreType)backingStoreType defer:(BOOL)flag NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

Comment: If ARC is turned off this code will run 'as is' in Xcode and the text fields are functional.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your help but it didn't help me... :(

I could resolve my problem.
I just added the method call `setActivationPolicy`.

```objectivec
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    [[[Window alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [application activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [application setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    
    [NSApp run];
}
```